# Storing object reference into dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

I have a two classes as shown below

```
public class StoredData
{
    private int totalLoops;

    [XmlElement("TotalLoops")]
    public int TotalLoops
    {
        get { return totalLoops; }
        set { totalLoops = Math.Abs(value); }
    }

    [XmlArray("LoopTypes"), XmlArrayItem("LoopType", typeof(LoopType))]
    public Dictionary<int, LoopType> loopTypes;

}
```

And a second class

```
public class LoopType
{

    public LoopType() { }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public TimeSpan StartTime;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public TimeSpan EndTime;

    [XmlAttribute(DataType="duration")]
    public string startTime
    {
        get { return XmlConvert.ToString(StartTime); }
        set { StartTime = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? TimeSpan.Zero : XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(value);}
    }

    [XmlAttribute(DataType = "duration")]
    public string endTime
    {
        get { return XmlConvert.ToString(EndTime); }
        set { EndTime = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? TimeSpan.Zero : XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(value); }
    } 
}
```

I am adding object of 'LoopType' into dictionary with following code.

```
StoredData data = new StoredData();
LoopType1 looptype = new LoopType();
looptype.StartTime = new TimeSpan(starthourtext, startminutetext, startsecondtext);
looptype.EndTime = new TimeSpan(endhourtext, endminutetext, endsecondtext);
data.loopTypes.Add(1,looptype);
```

above all code works fine but when i want to retrieve data from dictionary like i want to get say 'StartTime' of stored object in dictionary. For that i tried following code.

```
LoopType looptype;
data.loopTypes.TryGetValue(1, out looptype);
```

but i am unable to retrieve 'StartTime' value. It doesn't show any property in intellisense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is `LoopType1` declared? Did you mean `LoopType` instead?

Comment: Also, are you trying to get `StartTime` after de/serialization? If so, you are missing to check `startTime` string before getting values from `StartTime`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes i mean LoopType and i am currently not worried about deserialization.

Comment: Check the return from TryGetValue e.g. var result = data.loopTypes(i, looptype). If it is false, check the key you are passing in i to make sure it is the correct key.

Comment: Are you really doing all of this in a single function? Maybe you are destroying and/or creating a new `StoredData data` object between the initialization and call to `TryGetValue`.

Comment: The key that i am passing is the correct key. & return type of trygetvalue is also true.

Comment: There is no destroying or creating new StoredData data between initialization and trygetvalue.